# Config Property Shadowing

Tags: javascript, html, oop

Started playing with configured objects in JavaScript and something is causing me a few issues.

Check out this code:

```
function Monster() {
}

function Animal() {
  Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
    set: function(n) {  },
    get: function() { return "Jim"; } // hard-coded to demonstrate problem
  });
}

Monster.prototype = new Animal();

var monster = new Monster();
monster.name = "John";
monster.name // Still returns Jim. I need to assign the property to THIS object, so Jim is shadowed by John.
```

As the comment says, this is outputting "Jim", as the getter is hard-coded to return.

I don't want to change my prototype everytime I call monster.name - I want a NEW shadowed property on my monster instance. How can I manage that?

Comment: You're trying to use _prototypical_ inheritance to override a _per instance_ property on the base class.  It won't work.

Comment: So is there no way to assign monster.name without it being eaten by the prototype's definition? I don't want to change my prototype unless I directly try to modify monster.__proto__.name - otherwise I'd expect monster.name to point to a property on this object, not my proto.

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you? It shows how to reassign the name without changing the prototype's definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the property configurable:

```
function Animal() {
  Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
    configurable: true,
    set: function(n) {  },
    get: function() { return "Jim"; } // hard-coded to demonstrate problem
  });
}

Monster.prototype = new Animal();

var monster = new Monster();
Object.defineProperty(monster, 'name', {writable: true})
monster.name = "John";
monster.name
```

Comment: This isn't possibly in my example, but it does solve the shadowing issue.

Answer (score 3):

You hardcoded "Jim" in your getter function, so it will always return "Jim" not matter what. You need to store the value of your property in a local variable and also get it from there:

```
function Animal() {
  var myName = "Jim";
  Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
    set: function(n) { myName = n },
    get: function() { return myName; }
  });
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AB4WZ/)**

Comment: Virtually exactly what I thought, +1 for posting before I could even start writing.

Comment: Thanks for the post. But that was intentional to demonstrate how the property isn't being shadowed correctly when I try to override it in my subclass.

Comment: As I said, if you write literally `return "Jim";`, then this will always be the value of your property and it actually doesn't demonstrate anything. I'm not sure if I fully understand what you want but if you define your property the way I suggested, you can simply create Monster instances and change their name value. See updated fiddle.

Comment: If animal wasn't using defineProperty to create its property, then a NEW property would be assigned to my monster instance - shadowing the property animal has and thus not modifying my Animal prototype when I make changes to my monster instance. Your answer simply assumes I've made a silly mistake with the defineProperty function.

Comment: @JJJ You can use `defineProperty`. In fact, I still use it in my answer and I never said you should omit that. I still don't get what is wrong with my answer. Besides that I wrongly assumed that you made a mistake by writing `return "John"`, it successfully modifies the property of the Animal as you wanted it, or not? Did you try the fiddle?

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I don't think you had correctly read my question. In your Fiddle, the prototype Animal is still being modified, but normally in prototypical inheritance, the property gets set to the object you're working with, not its prototype. That was my problem. The mere fact that you had to force the prototype to store the value, demonstrates that this wasn't happening. Checkout http://jsfiddle.net/AB4WZ/1/

Comment: And now checkout http://jsfiddle.net/AB4WZ/2/ .. See how the values are correctly being shadowed?

Thanks for your input though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how you expect it to work. After all, your setter does nothing and your getter returns a constant.

Why not just do this?

```
function Animal() {
    this.name = "Jim";
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var monster = new Monster();
monster.name = "John";
monster.name // John
```

Comment: "Be able to know when a property is set/changed"

Comment: It's a contrived example to demonstrate how the property isn't being shadowed correctly. The lack of property shadowing is the issue I'm having. I need to use a define because I need to listen for changes to the property.